# Reverse the shuffling phase

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, sequential-analysis

It is very convenient to have `sklearn` library to split and shuffle the data with

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, shuffle=True)
```

The problem I have is I am working on a time-series problem. That problem can be seen as pictures. So I shuffle the "pictures", train, predict and reverse the shuffling part to get back the original series.

Once the training is done, I apply

```
Model = Model() #from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
Model.build_model_config(configs)
Model.model.summary()
...
Y_pred = Model.predict_point_by_point(X_test)
```

to get my prediction under a one-hot representation where

```
def predict_point_by_point(self, data):
   """
   Predict each timestep given the last sequence of true data, 
   in effect only predicting 1 step ahead each time
   """
   predicted = self.model.predict(data)
   predicted = predicted.reshape(data.shape[0],-1)
   return predicted
```

then I just apply

```
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
```

Here `y_pred` is shuffled and it is just a `numpy.array()`

e.g. `y_pred = array([0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, ...])`

How can reverse the shuffling part of `y_pred` so that it can be ordered?

Comment: Could you please explain what your terms "shuffled," "reverse," and "ordering" might mean?  I am having a hard time applying standard definitions of these terms in a way that makes any sense of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If your data has a time component you shouldn't do randomized train-test split in the first place. Neither should you shuffle - if your data has temporal nature, you'll distort it by shuffling.

Why is that? When you do this, you'll get points at time $t$ that are in the test set and some points $t'$ for $t' > t$ that are in train set. That makes model to use information from the future (but you don't want it right? You most likely want to *predict* the future).

What you should use instead is [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html). Other than that, try googling 'Python time series crossvalidation', there are lots of blog articles that describe it in details.

Comment: I am not asking you why it is good or not to shuffle the data for a time series problem. I've already know all that. Your answer is completely irrelavant. I am going to ask you to remove it please.

Comment: I'm not going to do that, because someone new might look at your question and assume that this is a valid splitting for some time-series related problem, which would mostly lead to invalid results.

Comment: BTW your question on shuffling has already been asked - [Inverse of random.shuffle()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577517/inverse-of-random-shuffle)